# Formula in partially visible merged cell not updating

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

That was a strange behaviour I encountered. Formulae within merged cells in excel which are also partially visible do not update even if automatic update of formula is enabled or F9 is pressed (recalculate). But I'm not even sure how to guarantee it, it doesn't quite make sense to me.

Example steps to reproduce:

1. Set up the following (the formula is `=COUNTIF(L4:R4,1)` and I added the pipes in K4 and R4 only to know what range I'm counting):

   [image]
2. Scroll until column C is the first column you can see and put 1 in the range. You should see this (or something similar I believe):

   [image]

As you can see, two of the 3 cells are being updated instead of all the three. You can however update the second cell by editing it (Press <kbd>F2</kbd> or click in the formula bar) and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> without changing anything), but that isn't practical if it's a report you're showing to a client, is it? :)

The current workaround for now is to 'hide' that the cells were merged by filling the background white, and center aligning where possible, but that's only a cure to reduce the symptoms as one could say.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to efficiently workaround this? Or that could be an in-built bug from Microsoft.

Also yes, merging is not appropriate for Excel, but presentation is important for those higher up people...

Comment: I'm getting it lagging behind too. If I type in M4=1 it stays at zero, but when I put 1 (or anything) in N4, it changes to 1. If I delete M4, it stays at 1 until I change another cell within range. Are you experiencing this as well? I'm on 2007, it's existed [for at least a while](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/336505-excel-2007-sp1-merged-cell-calculation-bug.html)

Comment: @Raystafarian Didn't find that one... Yes, experiencing the same. And it doesn't seem there's a workaround either. =/